# Need help onclick button

Tags: android, email, popupwindow

I want to be able to click a button and from clicking the button it opening up an email dialog box that allows me to send the email then go back to my app.

What i have as my code in my class is:

```
final Context context = getApplicationContext();    
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);          
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {               
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        sendEmail(context, new String[]{"abc@xyz.com"}, "Sending Email",
                  "Test Email", "I am body");
    }
});
```

}

```
public static void sendEmail(Context context, String[] recipientList,
        String title, String subject, String body) {
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);    
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");    
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipientList);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);   
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, title));
```

and in the activity layout I have:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="@string/send"
    android:onClick="processClicks" />
```

When I click on the button to go into this activity it gets kicked out the app before being able to check if the code works.

Comment: I don't see any JS/JQ here.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Car is to Carpet.

Comment: @SLaks can we get a comparison between jQuery and Android as well? `:)`

Comment: On-topic, @OP unless your app has a JS interpreter such as Rhino or a WebView somewhere, JS/jQuery is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

In the XML, remove the android:onClick="processclicks" line completely.

Having that in there will cause the activity to search for that onClick function named processClick, but since you're using a new OnClickListener, you don't need it. Since the activity won't find the processClick on click, it'll throw an error.

Comment: I took it out and still my program crashes if I even try to get into the activity with this button in it. Could it be the emulator?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<a href="mailto:email">email</a>
```